# SNCF strike in June 2014

Tags: event-based-effects, sncf

I will be traveling on the TGV this Sunday. They have not yet announced whether or not the strike will continue into Sunday. Is it possible for me to cancel my ticket and get a full refund just in case the strike continues? I need to buy an airplane ticket, but I don't want to get stuck with my TGV ticket fees, too, if the strike magically resolves by Sunday. Plane prices are going up quickly, so I need to decide soon. Thanks for any tips! PS, my trip is from Paris to Aix-en-Provence.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30419/french-strikes-using-idtgv-ticket-for-standard-sncf-tgv

Comment: Is it a refundable or non-refundable ticket?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer but there is [an official guide about the rules during the strike](http://www.sncf.com/fr/greve-questions-pratiques). It seems possible to get a refund even if the ticket would otherwise be non-refundable:

> Tous les billets, quels que soient les tarifs, y compris "non échangeables / non remboursables" tels que Prem's seront remboursés sans frais si vous en faites la demande au guichet et ce depuis le mercredi 4 juin 2014.

It does not sound contingent on your specific train being cancelled. At the beginning of the strike, it was possible to do it well in advance but an additional complication is that workers now decide each day if they want to go on so I don't know if the SNCF already offers refunds for Sunday. It's worth a try in any case but if you buy your plane ticket before you can make sure, you might very well end up with a non-refundable TGV ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, you can't get a refund on a non-refundable ticket until your train is announced as cancelled, but it probably doesn't matter...

If your train is cancelled, you'll be able to get a full refund of the ticket cost of the cancelled train, no matter what the conditions normally on it. You can do that at the station (expect epic queues), or via a few options detailed on [Info Lignes](http://www.infolignes.com/).

However, on most routes, there are still trains running, just not the full number. Checking for tomorrow morning, I'm seeing most but not all Paris to Aix-en-Provence-TGV trains running. If your train is cancelled, you'll be able to travel on any other service over that route on the same day. Won't be at the same time, may well involve a delay, and you might have to stand if you're unlucky (no promise of a seat if your train was cancelled), but you'll still be able to travel.

(Some routes everything or almost everything is cancelled, in which case you'd be out of luck beyond getting the refund, but Paris to Aix-en-Provence isn't currently in that category. If you have a refundable ticket, you could get a refund for any reason, but I'm assuming you don't if you have to ask here!)

Comment: Did you try it yourself? I am asking because the [official word](http://www.sncf.com/fr/greve-questions-pratiques) on this is not completely clear but it does suggest tickets could be refunded if you ask beforehand.

Comment: This is not true, getting or not a refund depends on the fare.

Comment: @Vince I assume Gagravarr and Stephanie are talking about non-refundable tickets, otherwise you don't need to invoke the strike…

Comment: @Relaxed most TGV tickets are refundable and neither the question nor the answer mentions that, so that just sounds very unclear to me.

Comment: @Vince And yet it sounds completely obvious to me…

Comment: @Relaxed I still wanted to travel, so I opted for taking different trains which (eventually) got me there. My reading of the rules (as translated by [loco2](http://help.loco2.com/article/172-strike-action-in-france-june-2014)) is that only if you train is cancelled does a non-refundable ticket become refundable

Comment: @Vince [“Tous les billets, quels que soient les tarifs, y compris "non échangeables / non remboursables" tels que Prem's seront remboursés sans frais”](http://www.sncf.com/fr/greve-questions-pratiques). Tickets are refundable if they're for travel during the strike period or if they're a return for a trip started during the strike period. This applies to all fares (except idTGV which has different rules) as long as the strike lasts, regardless of whether the train ends up running or not.

Comment: @Gilles That's interesting, the SNCF page in French suggests rules a lot more flexible on refunds than the Loco2 page in English does. I think that offer only applies during the strike though, so I'm not sure you can take it up until the unions announce that your day of travel is affected, which is normally 1-2 days before

Comment: @Gagravarr Indeed, that all-fares-are-refundable rule only applies during the strike. The unions have to announce the strike two days in advance, but that doesn't imply that the strike will lead to much traffic disruption, so SNCF could stop applying the rule if they decide that traffic will be almost normal. But in that case, travel would be possible, so there'd be no need for a refund.

Comment: Wouldn't help in the OP's case - they're wondering about a pre-emptive cancellation several days before a strike decision, so they can book a plane ticket instead

Answer (score 1):

As @Gagravarr said, you can take any tgv the day of the strike.

But unlike what he said, you may be able to cancel your ticket and get a refund.

If the fare is "Prem's" or iDTGV, then you cannot get a refund unless there is actually a strike, but you might not know before Saturday night.

If the fare is "Loisirs", "Loisirs Jeune" or bought with any discount card (Jeune, Senior, weekend), "TGV Pro" and I might forget some, then you can get a full refund if you cancel your ticket at least the day before. If you have an e-ticket then you can cancel it online, if it is a paper ticket then go to the station.

If you are not sure of the conditions of your ticket, read your reservation, it should be written.